# How to get rid of . and .. while scaning the folder creating an array in php?

Tags: php, regex, arrays, file, directory

If you scan a folder containing other folders AND files, how do you get rid of . and .. and files? How do you put in array only folders WITHOUT . and ..?
I would like to use regular expression, but I'm newbie and I can't get it right.
My code is now this but doesn't work:

> if(fnmatch("\.{1,2}",$dir_array[$i]) || is_file($dir_array[$i]){
>       unset($dir_array[$i]);
>    }else{ 
>   //other code
>   }

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are confusing fnmatch and regular expressions in your code. To get all files and directories except the special ones, use this:

```
$dir_array = array_diff($dir_array, array(".", ".."));
```

Alternatively, if you iterate the array anyway, you can test each element like this:

```
foreach ($dir_array as $name) {
    if (($name != "..") && ($name != ".")) {
        // Do stuff on all files and directories except . ..
        if (is_dir($name)) {
            // Do stuff on directories only
        }
    }
}
```

In php<5.3, you can exclusively [use a callback function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php), too:

```
$dir_array = array_filter($dir_array,
  create_function('$n', 'return $n != "." && $n != ".." && is_dir($n);'));
```

(See Allain Lalonde's answer for a more verbose version)

Since php 5.3, this can be written [nicer](http://wiki.php.net/rfc/closures):

```
$dir_array = array_filter($dir_array,
  function($n) {return $n != "." && $n != ".." && is_dir($n);});
```

Finally, combining array_filter and the first line of code of this answer yields an (insignificantly) slower, but probably more readable version:

```
$dir_array = array_filter(array_diff($dir_array, array(".", "..")), is_dir);
```

Comment: I didn't mean . and .. are files, I just wanted to delete these directories from array together with possible files. But I like how you used array_diff. Thanks

Comment: Oops, my bad. Sorry, on rereading I can't understand why I wrote it that way. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You don’t need a regular expression to test this. Just use plain string comparison:

```
if ($dir_array[$i] == '.' || $dir_array[$i] == '..' || is_file($dir_array[$i])) {
    unset($dir_array[$i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This may do it.

```
function is_not_meta_dir($file_name) {
  // return true if $filename matches some pattern.
  // without knowing the format of your $dir_array
  return $file_name != '.' && $file_name != '..';
}

$new_dir_array = array_filter($dir_array, 'is_not_meta_dir');
```

Comment: That looks like lambda ... uhmmm .. create_function could beautify the code. Anyway, you should decide between $filename and $file_name ;)

Comment: typo. Dang my dependence on IDEs.  Also, create_function would be an alternative to the above, but I'm not sure I'd consider it more beautiful.

Comment: @Allain Lalonde: I agree create_function looks ugly, but I prefer it from an ivory tower point of view ;). Since 5.3, you can write array_filter($d_a, function($fn) {return $fn!="." && $fn != "..";}); which is definitely nicer.

Answer (score 1):

no regex is needed, just unset() the first two values.

```
$d = dir($dir);
unset($d[0]);
unset($d[1]);
```

Comment: This requires no repetitive if's or iteration and would perform the fastest, so +1 to you sir.  This is as simple and clean as it gets.

Comment: First I did it also like this, but then I thought what if . and .. are not [0] and [1]. I try to do everything as universal as possible.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it like this:

```
$items = array();
$handle = opendir('path/to/dir');
while (($item = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
    if (! in_array($item, array('.', '..'))) {
        $items[] = $item;
    }
}
closedir($handle);

print_r($items);
```

Although, I'd rather prefer [DirectoryFilterDots](http://www.php.net/~helly/php/ext/spl/classDirectoryFilterDots.html) but it's kind of rare in the available PHP distributions.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this (code may not work without effort since I haven't worked in PHP for years)

```
<?
if ($handle = opendir('/myPath')) 
  {
  while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle)))
  { 
    if (bool is_dir ( $file ) && substring($file,0,1) != ".")
      {
        $filesArray[] = $file; // this is the bit I'm not sure of the syntax for. 
      }
    }
  }
?>
```

*EDIT* misread the question - This should now add to the array all the folder names ion myPath that are not "." or ".."

Answer (score 0):

```
        $pathsArr = array();
    foreach (explode($dirSeparator, $currentPath) as $path) {
        if (strlen($path) && $path !== '.') {
            if ($path === '..') {
                // die('.....');
                array_pop($pathsArr);
            } else {
                $pathsArr[] = $path;
            }
        }
    }

    $realpath = $winDrive . $dirSeparator . implode($dirSeparator, $pathsArr);
```